# When testing a rake task, why does rspec receive this method twice when it is only called once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm attempting to test a rake task, and getting a very strange result.

```
expected: 1 time with arguments:
received: 2 times with arguments:
```

The code in question only calls the method once, and I am unable to work out where the extra call is coming from.

This is the first time I've written tests for a rake task, so I may have overlooked something obvious. Does the following look like a reasonable approach?

```
#spec/lib/scheduled_tasks_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
require 'rake'
MyApp::Application.load_tasks
load File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'tasks', 'scheduled_tasks.rake')

RSpec.describe "scheduled rake tasks" do
  describe 'Initialization' do

    let!(:team)  { create :team }
    let!(:admin) { create :user, role: 'admin' }

    it 'should call the GeneratePdf job for each team' do

      expect(GenerateReportJob).to(
        receive(:perform_later).with(
          [admin], team
        ).once.and_call_original
      )
      Rake::Task['scheduled_tasks:generate_reports'].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

The rake task I'm testing is very simple

```
namespace :scheduled_tasks do
  task generate_reports: :environment do
    admins = Admin.where(role: 'admin')
    # byebug
    Team.all.each do |team|
      GenerateReportJob.perform_later(admins, team) 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Does user factory create another team?

Comment: thanks @SergioTulentsev. No, admin factory sets only email and password.  Using byebug, I can check only 1 team exists just before the job is called.

Comment: Check while inside the job. Immediately before `Team.all.each`

Comment: I've added the byebug call to the rake code above. Is that the correct place? If so, `Team.all.size = 1`

Comment: Also it _looks_ like you might be loading tasks twice. Not sure if that'd make one task name be associated  with two identical chunks of code.

Comment: Well, in this case, can't reproduce :)

Comment: you mean `MyApp::Application.load_tasks`? I got that from an example I came across via Google. Let me try removing

Comment: On a related note, I never test rake tasks (mainly because of this test setup overhead). If task logic needs to be tested, I put the logic in a regular object and test that object. The rake task then simply calls the object and contains no testable code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev good point, I should refactor this! Anyway, you were correct about loading tasks twice. Removing `load File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'tasks', 'scheduled_tasks.rake')` fixes the issue! Care to post as the answer? Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're loading the task definition twice here.

```
MyApp::Application.load_tasks
load File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'tasks', 'scheduled_tasks.rake')
```

Apparently, this causes name `"scheduled_tasks:generate_reports"` point to *two* [identical] chunks of code.